# Cassandra connection pool not working inside the fork - C++

Tags: c++, cassandra

We have a C++ Web Service which does data processing and DB is Cassandra.

The Web Service reads the request and fork the child and does the action.

We need to pool Cassandra connection and cassandra document says, the driver could pool the connection if the session, cluster and keyspace are same.

To do that, we have created the connection before the service starts and use that inside the forked child. However, inside the fork the connection is not responding.

Code snipped is this:

```
void Service_Ready_Handler()
{
    // Do the DB connection here
    connectCassandra();
}
void ServiceHandler(session, request)
{
    // fork the child and do the process
    if ( fork() == 0 ) // child
    {
         // fetch the data from DB for the request
         // do the additional process
         // prepare the response and write to parent
    }

    // if the child is done, send the response
}
```

However, the connection is working fine, but the "fetching" data part is hanging and not giving any information at all.
Cant we pass the Cassandra connection (session and cluster) ?
What is the other option to pool the connection for Cassandra?

Appreciate your support in advance.

Thanks,

Comment: `fork()` ing a new process on each connection is nice and simple, but usually doesn't perform very well. Consider using a thread pool or passing new connections to existing worker processes or similar.

Comment: Out code is legacy and not thread safe and have to use fork only (not thread). The connection created outside the fork is not available inside the fork. Are you suggesting to use some shared memory or something to store the connection handler?

Comment: Ok, the code is not thread safe, so using threads is out. Processes it is. There's still no reason to incurr the overhead of starting and tearing down a new process for every connection. You could, for example, have a pool of pre-created worker processes that you distribute work to by passing then the filedescriptor of the new connection via a pipe, shared memory, a unix domain socket or similar. There are many ways to do it that don't have the cost of full process creation/destruction on each connection - not as simple though, but better performing (which may/may not matter).

Comment: Yes, agree, we have decided to use the DB's pooling concept and not do that through application code, to avoid the overhead. Thank you.